# How to add data validation in a range of cell in a range of cell in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
heading_list= ['apple','type','Action','method']
for j, t in enumerate(heading_list):
            worksheet.write(row + 1, col + j, t,header_format)
            if t == 'Action':
                worksheet.data_validation(row+1,3,col+j,3 ,{'validate': 'list', 'source': ['Insert', 'Update']})
```

I want to add the validation to the particular row ..How will i do?worksheet.data_validation(row+1,3,col+j,3 ,{'validate': 'list', 'source': ['Insert', 'Update']})
is not working accordingly

Comment: Should that be `t == ‘action’`? I.e., lowercase.

Comment: even Action also is not working @jmcnamara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working. I think the issue is that the (row, col) co-ordinates are wrong and the data validation isn't in the cell that you expect it to be in.

Fixing the (row, col) co-ordinates should give the expected result:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

header_format = workbook.add_format({'border': 1, 'bg_color': '#C6EFCE'})

row = 0
col = 0

heading_list = ['apple', 'type', 'action', 'method']
for j, t in enumerate(heading_list):
    worksheet.write(row, col + j, t, header_format)
    if t == 'action':
        worksheet.data_validation(row + 1, col + j, row + 1, col + j,
                                  {'validate': 'list',
                                   'source': ['Insert', 'Update']})


workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]